# how can i send parameters with <a> for set query MySQL in smarty & Php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i want create grid with bootstrap in smarty / php

in grid i have name, family, ... & **edit button**.

when i click in btn edit, modal popup open, but i don't know how sent **record ID** to function for set query & show in modal:

**sample code:**

[www.bootply.com/webdeveloper/iQrK1Yxlkk](http://www.bootply.com/webdeveloper/iQrK1Yxlkk)

**btn:**

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static">
  Edit User
</a>
```

**Modal:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        username: ...
        <br>
        Password: ...
        <br>
        avatar: ...
        <br>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution:

- remove attributes `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModal"`
- Add `data-id` attribute for tag `a`
- Add bind jquery to `click` for tag `a`
- when user click to tag a:

  - Insert record ID into hidden text input in modal form
  - Run bootstrap modal manually `$('#myModal').modal()`

Hope it will help

**EDIT:**

Also in documentation i see special event when modal run (probably it is more bootstrap.js way...):

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   // get record ID here
})
```

so you can use e.target to get attributes of tag `a`